# 256X8 RAM chip question

Tags: ram

I have a problem in my textbook "How many 256X8 Ram chips are needed to provide a memory capacity of 4096 bytes?".  I know that the answer is supposed to be 16, I'm just not sure why.  It seem like it should be 2 since it's 256X8 as opposed to 256 alone.  Basically, what I'm trying to say is (256x8)*2=4,096 instead of (256x8)*16 which equals 32,768.  Why is it 16?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

256x8 = 256 cells that hold 8 bits each, so the total capacity of that chip is 256 bytes (or 2048 bits). `4096/256=16`

Comment: Ah, I feel like an idiot.  I thought it was 2048 bytes instead of bits. Thanks!